# Вывод ленты rss

Tags: xml, php, rss

нужно вывести все записи

```
http://blogs.yandex.ru/search.xml?text=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%BE+%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%BB%D0%BE&holdres=mark&ft=blog%2Ccomments%2Cmicro&server=twitter.com&date=on&from_day=01&from_month=04&from_year=2014&to_day=30&to_month=04&to_year=2014
```

справа есть rss, но так как первый раз сталкиваюсь с этим, то вообще не знаю что делать,
искал parse rss xml, но warning выбивает, и в результате ничего, хотя в warning`ах проскакивал html код

Comment: rss - это самый обычный xml, просто оформленный по определенным правилам. Ищите как парсить xml, тогда сможете и rss парсить.

Comment: [simplexml_load_file][1]


  [1]: http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: rss, я прочитал, там есть ссылки на результаты поиска, как все ссылки результата вывести

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Циклом